# My ubuntu with unity not loading after last reboot

Tags: 11.10, unity, boot, mouse

I have asus u36sd and after last reboot I can't start up my ubuntu 11.10. Usually I suspend my notebook by closing cover but today I reboot it and it not starting up. Booting flowing by normal till to login screen but if I move mouse cursor after that image immediately switch to console (without any error; only normal loading startup processes) and back to login screen. I can type my password and boot continuing loading but after few moment it again switch back to dark console and switch again to login screen.

I can load recovery mode but if I try touch my cursor (by mouse or internal notebook touchpad) it again switch back to console and to login screen. But if I use only keyboard it work fine.
Where I can see detailed log information about my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the touchpad if there's an option using the Fn key of your notebook's keyboard (as soon as the login screen appears). Also disconnect any external mice.

Then type Ctrl+Alt+F1 and input your username and password. Then, in terminal type:
dmesg | tail
Then plug in a mouse and move it a bit. Then rerun the command "dmesg | tail" (without quotes) and try to see what additional info was printed after you plugged in the mouse and moved it.

Maybe there will be a tip somewhere along these lines...

Comment: I see error only with "init: lightdm main process (1311) terminated with status 1" after all this manipulation. But if I can't disable touchpad by FN hotkey. It still crush my system.